# How to get string representation (like repr in Python)

Tags: string-manipulation

I have a string variable. I want to obtain another string which contains the representation of the string variable content itself.

```
s = "a \n b"
```

I need to get a string containing the exact characters from above, including the escape character `\` and the `"`:

```
r = "\"a \\n b\""
```

Is there a function that can do that?

The output should be similar to `repr("a \n b")` from Python:

*This function makes an attempt to return a string that would yield an object with the same value when passed to `eval()`*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use `ToString`

```
ToString["a\nb", InputForm] // InputForm
```

> ```
> "\"a\\nb\""
> ```

Adding `// InputForm` is not strictly necessary.  It will influence only the printing of the output, not its structure.  By default, Mathematica does not show quotes around strings in the output, and it expands escaped characters (such as `\n`) to their meaning (an actual newline in this case).  `InputForm` will change this behaviour and will cause Mathematica to show quotes and escaped characters.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know that `ToString` acts like this for `InputForm`. +1.

Comment: @Leonid `ToString` is the function to convert a Mathematica expression to a string prepresentation.  Otherwise one could use `ExportString[..., "Package"]` to achieve a similar effect.

Comment: I am aware of the general purpose of `ToString`. But I rarely use the second argument of `ToString`, and in particular I did not know that it acts in this way when you set it to `InputForm`. I did need this functionality a few times as well, particularly [here](https://groups.google.com/group/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/browse_thread/thread/c1f4ab24db8a8542), where I used some half-baked and inferior custom version.

Comment: @Szabolcs I added the `//InputForm` to show the full structure of the string, and to make it clear that something really did change.

Comment: @Brett Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this:

```
r = ToBoxes[s]
```

and you're done. In case you need additional escape levels, just iterate `ToBoxes`.

Comment: `ToString["a\nb", InputForm]` (my answer) already returns the requested result.  Don't be fooled by the quotes not being printed, they're there even if the system doesn't print them.  Just start editing the output cell ...

Comment: That's what I mean: do I understand what he wants? I added another escape level, as you can see with "Show Expression" or by exporting as text... maybe that's too much escaping, I'm not sure.

Comment: My concern about your solution is that applying `ToExpression` to it does not give the same expression we started with (it throws an error).  It's possible to influence the printing of the output like this: `ToString["a\nb", InputForm] // InputForm`.  This will show the quotes and the escapes without changing the meaning of the expression.  `ToExpression[%]` will return the string we started with.

Comment: @Szabolc OK, the question was much simpler than how I interpreted it. In this case, my answer can of course be simplified, too. So I'll do that now.